# Z-index not working, even with position absolute

Tags: css, z-index

Doing a Next.js project, here's the issue:

[image]

The component:

```
function Team() {
 
     const VerticalCircles = () => {
    let circles = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return circles.map(() => <div className={styles.circle} />);
  };

  return (
      <div className={styles.team}>
        <div className={styles.diagonalSVG}></div>
        <div className={styles.title}>
          <h1>Meet the team</h1>
          <p>Responsible for creating amazing memories</p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.teamSection}>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            {teamMembers.map((member) => (
              <div className={styles.teamBox} key={member.id}>
                <span className={styles.diagonalSpan} />
                <Image src={member.src} width={300} height={450} />
                <div>
                  <div className={styles.presentation}>
                    <h4>{member.name}</h4>
                    <p>{member.username}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={styles.description}>
                    <p>{member.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Slider>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.verticalCircles}>
          <VerticalCircles />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.join}>
          <h2>Ready to join us?</h2>
          <p>Book a walk and start your journey with Novanoid.</p>
          <button>BOOK A WALK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

And here's the scss module:

```
.team {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.diagonalSVG {
  background: $green;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 40%, 0 100%);
  padding: 40px 0px;
  height: 100px;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  & h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  & p {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: $grey;
    font-size: 15.5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
}

.verticalCircles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  & .circle {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: $dark;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}

.teamSection {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.teamBox {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 240px;
  max-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2.8px 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.011),
    6.7px 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.016),
    12.5px 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02),
    22.3px 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.024),
    41.8px 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.029),
    100px 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  transition: all 0.2s ease, max-height 1s ease;

  & h4 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: $green;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  & p {
    color: $grey;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  & img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    z-index: -2;
  }
  & .diagonalSpan {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top: 310px;
    content: "";
    width: 110%;
    height: 50px;
    right: -20px;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  & .description {
    display: none;
    text-align: start;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: $dark;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
    animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  }
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    max-height: 800px;
    & img {
      filter: grayscale(0%);
    }

    & .presentation {
      display: none;
    }
    & .description {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

.join {
  text-align: center;
  & h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  & p {
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  & button {
    @include novanoid-btn(white, $green);
    margin: 10px 0 60px 0;
  }
}
```

Basically, **.verticalCircles** overwrite the **.description** div. I've removed the Slider and still, it gets over. I've tried everything from this website: https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/

- Added position relative to Slider, teamBox (div), .description

Another thing, **.verticalCircles** goes behind **.join** ("Ready to join us?"), so it seems to have something to do with the way .teamSection or .teamBox is structured...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out! The problem was here:

```
     <div>
         <div className={styles.presentation}>
                <h4>{member.name}</h4>
                <p>{member.username}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.description}>
                <p>{member.description}</p>
              </div>
     </div>
```

This div needed a className and a background of white, the z-index was working perfectly :)

Answer (score -1):

add following css in your code:

```css
.team {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still does not work :/ The circles get behind the image but in front of the text... I've added position: relative and z-index:1 also to .presentation and .description, but doesn't work.

Comment: so,you can put .verticalcircle to outside of .team and try.can it work...

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still not working... This is a headache. I will try to isolate these two sections, .verticalCircles and .teamBox to better understand it.

Comment: sorry,  i can't help you correctly....sorry bro

Comment: No worries! Thanks for taking the time to help :)